# Connecting an EC2 instance to an RDS volume on another AWS Account

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have two different AWS accounts running EC2 instances and RDS volumes set up in the following way:

**AWS Account #1**

- EC2 1(Production)
- RDS 1(Production)

**AWS Account #2**

- EC2 2(Development)
- RDS 2(Development)

The reason I separated the development and production was to take advantage of the AWS free tier usage while we test our app.

My question is whether it's possible for me to access the **RDS 2 (Production)** from **EC2 1 (Development)** for testing purposes, and if so how I'd go about doing it. I've been playing around with the VPC settings and can't seem to get it work.

Basically can I access the RDS of one AWS account from an EC2 of another AWS account that I own?

Comment: You could open up the security group on the production RDS instance to allow incoming traffic from the elastic IP of the development environment

Comment: Hmm I only seem to be

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to keep your traffic inside the VPC realms, then you need to create a `Peering Connection` between the 2 VPCs. Peering Connections can be created across different AWS accounts very easily by referencing the VPC ID in the other account, and then you will need to login to that account and Accept/Approve the connection.

Then you need to create rules in your routing tables to let the 2 networks communicate.

Comment: Thanks for reply - I'm working my way through setting this up. I've connected the two accounts via **Peering Connections**, and added the  CIDR peer block of the production account to the route table of the dev machine, but I still can't seem to access the MySQL server. Any thing else I'm missing?

Comment: @Eugene You will need to create the peering connection on both accounts and update the route tables on both accounts to point to each other so packets can go both ways. If you've already done this, then you will need to also add the CIDR blocks to the RDS security groups for both instances on the appropriate port for your DB type (3306 for MySQL, for instance)